# How do i create an UPDATE statement using group by?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-update

I have the following update query which doesn't work, and need help getting this update to work. any help is appreciated.

```
update polls 
   set updated_by=2 
where updated_by=1 
group by poll_date, server_id, product_id;
```

Comment: `UPDATE` doesn't allow for using `GROUP BY`, please check proper syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html  It's not clear what are you trying to achieve using `GROUP BY`, please explain.

Comment: im trying to remove duplicates from my database, by flagging them as updated_by=2

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as `GROUP BY` is used to change how the result set is presented. `UPDATE` doesn't have output, so there is nothing to be grouped.

Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming that there is an unique id in the table (primary key), this query can mark duplicates as `2`:

```
UPDATE polls p1
JOIN
( SELECT id
  FROM polls p1
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM polls p2
    WHERE p1.poll_date = p2.poll_date
      AND p1.server_id = p2.server_id
      AND p1.product_id = p2.product_id
      AND p2.id < p1.id
  )
) p2
 ON p1.id = p2.id
SET p1.updated_by = 2
WHERE p1.updated_by = 1
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b83b/1

Comment: Hi, that almost works but i need it to set the highest or max quantity to 2, in the duplicate set. It just sets the one with the highest id instead. I updated the demo to show actual data. thanks for helping.